# writing integers to a file in c

Tags: c, file, printf

I need to print integers to a file. I will post the code below. The output of this code is a empty file, it does not contain the integers.

```
FILE *out1;
out1 = fopen(outfile, "w");
if( out1 == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the output file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
int paste = noptr->no;
printf("message received %d\n", paste);
fprintf(out1,"%d\n", paste);
printf("printed!\n");
fclose(out1);
```

Comment: your code works fine. Just for test check with  `out1 = fopen("outfile", "w");` and `int paste=1000;`.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct output file?

Comment: Show the rest of your code, especially where *outfile* and *noptr* are defined and initialized.

Comment: yes, the output file is created by the program itself. I deleted it before compiling all the times. The file is created every time, but it is empty.

Comment: printf("noptr->no = %d\n",noptr->no); prints the correct output so i dont think that the problem is related with it. variable outfile has the value "out" and the program creates "out", but it is empty.

Comment: @gray_malkin Show full code mate.. especially the parts where outfile is manipulated or even mentioned

Comment: if `printf("noptr->no = %d\n",noptr->no); ` prints the expected output, why, instead of assigning `noptr->no` to `paste`, try `fprintf(out1, "%d\n", noptr->no);`, see if that helps... and assign the return value of `fprintf` to `paste` and output that value... do check that, too! Also try `printf("%d\n", ferror(out1));` after each call to `fprintf`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem i did all these, still i get an empty output file.

Comment: @gray_malkin: Yes, but what was your on-screen output for each of the above (`printf("%d\n", ferror(out1));` and `printf("%d\n", paste);` for example)... with the code provided, there's not enough to go on here...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Perhaps your `int` is 0 and you open your file in text editor. Check output file size.

Comment: And still, in this case the output file shouldn't be empty, it should rather contain '0' (and a newline, of course).

Comment: yes, sure my bad. So only suggestion is you write in the wrong file

Comment: how do i check output file size?

Comment: in linux you can use `ls -l filename` it shows file size and creation date. In windows in console cd to directory with file and type dir

Comment: i checked the size and it is 0. But shouldn't it be zero because it is empty? creation date is the time when i last compiled the program.

Comment: If the size is zero it should be empty. So I think function `open` creates file and there was an error in fprintf and it does not store anything to file

Comment: @jediserg so what should i do? do you have an advice?

Comment: Check the fprintf result. If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned. `if(fprintf(...) < 0) printf("error")`

Comment: You can use `perror ("The following error occurred");` to write the last error message

Comment: What does fprintf return? It should return the number of bytes had been written. Is it zerro?

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to write to a file with ***name*** outfile,

```
out1 = fopen("outfile", "w");
```

Comment: It wouldn't even compile if this was the bug. The OP gets output.

Comment: outfile is a variable and printf("noptr->no = %d\n",noptr->no); prints the correct value.